# Listar grupos do AD através de uma query

Tags: sql, active-directory

Estou querendo fazer uma consulta direto ao Adctive Directory. Preciso saber quais os grupos as Views estão vinculadas, o mesmo vale para os usuários.

A estrutura, para vecês entenderem melhor: é criado um grupo onde é vinculado uma view, para esse grupo da view é criado outro grupo, que estão os usuários que tem acesso a view.

```
SELECT
       *
FROM OPENQUERY(ADSI,'<LDAP://DC=dominio,DC=com,DC=br>;(&(objectCategory=person)(objectClass=user));
     sn,
    sAMAccountName,
    displayName,
    mail,
    telephoneNumber,
    mobile,
    physicalDeliveryOfficeName,
    department,
    division;
    subtree')
```

Acima é o que eu tenho, que me retorna todos os usuários do AD.

Answer (score 1):

Encontrei a solução para esse meu problema.

```
(&(objectClass=group)(memberOF=CN=NomeView,OU=NomedaPasta,DC=dominio,DC=com,DC=br)
```

Lembrando que é necessário ter conhecimento da estrutura no Active Directory. OU é usado para indicar a pasta, sendo que deve colocar todos os nomes das pastas até o destino. Cada OU se refere a uma pasta.

Comment: Uma dúvida as pastas definidas com "OU" são os grupos que o usuário está inserido?